Browser router path is added api request
I have a create-react-app using react-router-dom and axios
The application contains a route
/view-details/:planId/:itemId
When application navigates to the above mentioned path, the api request is prefixed with above mentioned like follows
https://localhost:3000/view-details/1/api/details
instead it should have been
https://localhost:3000/api/details
I haven't configured the baseURL in axios, so I am assuming its empty. This issue occurs only when there is a param in browser path. I believe the issue is not with axios configuration since some images also contain the path like https://localhost:3000/view-details/1/assets/img/img.png instead of https://localhost:3000/assets/img/img.png
Below is my package.json

{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  // omitted scrips, dependencies and irrelevant setup
}

Solution tried:
updated "homepage": "/" in package.json -> didn't work
So, I am not sure if I am missing anything in configuration.
Updated answer
I updated my api url from `api/details` to `/api/details` and that solved the issue. So it means I was using relative url instead of absolute. Applied the same logic to asset path and that also worked.

You didn't show how you make the api request

axios.get("api/details")

This wil be the answer for you.
If you specify a relative URL like 'api/details', the requested URL will be made like https://localhost:3000/view-details/1/api/details. So you should set the URL as /api/details.

Thanks for this. In my case the url is "api/details". In fact when I changed it to "/api/details" it worked. So that basically meant that I was using relative URLs api/details instead of using absolute /api/details.

The last problem that still remains is assets are still loading as https://localhost:3000/view-details/1/assets/img/img.png instead of https://localhost:3000/assets/img/img.png
